# How to get rid of the following errors?

Tags: android, notifications, bluetooth-lowenergy, texas-instruments

I've been trying to bring notification in my Android app by using TI Sensor Tag. I looked up the user guide and found the following code. Can anyone please help me on how to get rid of the errors and bring in a proper code for a notification pop up on my android app.

```
    package ti.android.ble.sensortag;

    public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGattCharecteristic c) {
        Integer encodedInteger = c.getIntValue(FORMAT_UNIT8, 0);

        SimplKeysStatus newValue = SimpleKeysStatus.values()[encodedInteger %4];
        model.setSimpleKeysStatus(newValue);


    }

    public enum SimpleKeysStatus {
        // Warning: The order in which these are defined matters.
        OFF_OFF, OFF_ON, ON_OFF, ON_ON;
    }
```

The errors are as follows:

Multiple markers at this line

```
- Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
- Syntax error, insert "enum Identifier" to complete EnumHeader
- Syntax error on token "void", @ expected
- Syntax error on token "{", ; expected after this token
- Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write code, you need to be very careful with correct placement of things like brackets, commas, semicolons.

For example, you have a semicolon at the end of your enum definition, which should not be there. It should be something more like:

```
public enum SimpleKeysStatus {OFF_OFF, OFF_ON, ON_OFF, ON_ON}
```

Fix this and you should find that some of the subsequent errors go away too.